# Javascript array reverse function unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand why situation 1 and situation 2 don't return the same results.

Situation 1 :

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var array2 = array1.reverse();

console.log(array1); // ["3", "2", "1"]
console.log(array2); // ["3", "2", "1"] Why this doesn't work ?
```

Situation 2 :

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var array2 = array1;

console.log(array1);           // ["1", "2", "3"]
console.log(array2.reverse()); // ["3", "2", "1"] Why this works ?
```

Comment: Your suggested output for the second example is incorrect. Could this be adding to your confusion? [See what I'm talking about](https://jsfiddle.net/mq43eyb4/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Corrected. it was a simple copy/paste mistake and no it wasn't adding to my confusion.

Comment: I downvote. This question, despite it's popularity, is an example of insufficient research effort (not reading the docs). The title is also quite poor meaning it won't help much of the google users that might be having this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Situation 1`

> The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object in place, **mutating** the array, and **returning** a reference to the array.

In `Situation 2` you have the **same** reference. You are printing `array1` array **before** reverse it.

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var array2 = array1;

console.log(array1);           // [ '1', '2', '3' ]
console.log(array2.reverse()); // [ '3', '2', '1' ]
console.log(array1);           // [ '3', '2', '1' ]
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call [`.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) you are reversing the value, and then returning the array.

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]; //Create a new array
var array2 = array1.reverse();//Reverse array1 and assign it to array2
```

Any changes made to `array1` are also reflected in `array2` in this case, the confusion arose from the fact that you were printing the value before it was modified.

Comment: Oh wow, I just noticed that in situation 1 ["3", "2", "1"] was returned and not ["1", "2", "3"]... I thought I was creating 2 arrays in my situations but I was only creating 2 pointers to the same array right ?

Comment: @m-a.D Correct - you really just have two arrays that are *pointing* to the same object, so a change in one affects *both* (see my answer for more detail).

Answer (score 4):

`reverse()` modifies and returns the original array. See [MDN Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var array2 = array1;             // point to the same object

console.log(array1);             // original array1 (["1", "2", "3"])
console.log(array2.reverse());   // reverses array2 and array1 since they
                                 //   point to the same object and returns
                                 //   array2 (["3", "2", "1"])
console.log(array1);             // check that array1 was reversed (["3", "2", "1"])
console.log(array1.reverse() === array1);   // returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object in place, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array. Thus, it does not return the reversed array.

CHECK the manuel.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) does *two* things:

- It mutates the array it's given by reversing it
- It returns a reference to the array that was just reversed

Let's take a look at your examples and what's going on/

#### Situation One

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];  // Creates new array
var array2 = array1.reverse(); // Reverse array1 and stores reference to array1 in array2

// Since array1 and array2 point to the same object, they will have
// the same values since they are pointing to the same object
console.log(array1); // ["3", "2", "1"]
console.log(array2); // ["3", "2", "1"]
```

#### Situation Two

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];  // Creates new array
var array2 = array1;           // array2 now holds a reference to array1

// Same as the previous example, array1 and array2 both have the
// same values since they are pointing to the same object    
console.log(array1);           // ["1", "2", "3"]

// Now we reverse array2, which reverses array1 AND array2
console.log(array2.reverse()); // ["3", "2", "1"]

// array1 is now also reversed
console.log(array1);           // ["3", "2", "1"]
```

In the second situation, after you call `array2.reverse()`, *both* `array1` and `array2` become reversed since they're pointing to the same object reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `reverse()` change the array itself. That means, if you write `var array2 = array1.reverse()` then array1 is reversed. Array1 contains now the reversed entries and on the other side array2 is initialized with this reversed array. Therefor you have the same output.

On the second example with `var array2 = array1` you have two variable referencing the same array.
First you print out array1 which result in normal order. As second step you reverse array2 and print it out. The order has changed now. But if you print out array1 again now, the result will be the array in reversed order, because array1 and array2 refer to the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pobh4ech/))

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var array2 = array1.slice(0).reverse();

console.log(array1, array2);
```

Using `slice(0)` creates a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Array is object in javascript so assigning an array to another array simply assigns its reference so both of them will be pointing to same object. Whereas for this situation it is better to use slice function of array to copy data of array to another like

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var array2 = array1.slice().reverse();

console.log(array1); // ["1", "2", "3"]
console.log(array2); // ["3", "2", "1"]
```